# Brackets.io < data-bracket-id=" " >issue. How to remove out when using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, brackets, chrome-dev-editor

I'm using Brackets to write HTML/CSS but when I do Live Previews and open Chrome Dev tools(Ctr+Shift+i). It's always have **data-bracket-id=" "** insert into every tag. It make confuse when reading on there. But when I try using Sublime Text then open Chrome Dev Tools, it's ok, and also same with Editor. Please advise I prefer to using Brackets than Sublime Text. Please see issue below.

```html
<body data-brackets-id="70">

<h1 data-brackets-id="71">Box Model</h1>

<div data-brackets-id="72" id="box">
  <div data-brackets-id="73" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just disable live preview on brackets

Comment: @Phiter   Great!! Thanks.